# Too many WSP5018: Loaded WSIT configuration in server.log

Tags: web-services, glassfish, jax-ws

In my glassfish server.log I found too many and frequent messages as

WSP5018: Loaded WSIT configuration from file: file:/usr/src/glassfishv3.0.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/MY_APP/META-INF/wsit-client.xml.

I think it appears when jax-ws client init the port for a webservice.
I call a webservice by making it in ejb session bean.

How to avoid to have many and many info message about it?
I mistake in initialize the webservice client?